# Why isn't the sum of a `Vec<i64>` known to be `Option<i64>`?

Tags: rust

If I run

```rust
fn my_func(v: Vec<i64>) {
    let sum = v.into_iter().sum();
}

fn main() {
}
```

then Rust wants me to provide a type annotations and write

```rust
v.into_iter().sum::<i64>()
```

I'm just trying to understand - why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the [`sum` method on `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum)
you see that it is generic over the output type with `S: Sum<Self::Item>`.

This means you are free to implement the `Sum` trait for you own types and sum a `Vec<i64>` into you custom type. So the compiler can not infer what the type should be.

By the way the output is a `S` not an `Option<S>`. The `sum::<i64>` of an empty vector is `0`.

Rust could have decided to define sum in "your" way:

```
fn sum(self) -> Option<Self::Item>
where
  Self::Item : Add<Output=Self::Item>
```

but they did not to make it more general.